# Once checkbox is checked textbox is manatory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Ihis is the code of check box in view:

```
@Html.SimpleCheckBox("twoFactorAuthentication",Model.users.twoFactorAuthentication)
```

This is the condition on code side:

```
if((string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LanID) || user.LanID == " ") && user.twoFactorAuthentication ==true)
{
    throw new Exception("Please enter valid Lan ID");
}
```

Before the `&&` condition is working properly but `user.twoFactorAuthentication == true` this condition is not working properly.

Comment: `this condition is not working properly.` and how is it not working as you expect? How is `user` and `user.twoFactorAuthentication` being constructed/set?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working properly"?  How specifically is this failing?  Where is `user` defined?  Where are its values set?  When you debug, what specifically fails?